# Why this DropdownMenu doesn't work in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a DropdownMenu in WPF with the code-behind in VB. For any reason that I can't realise this DropdownMenu is not working as I would like to.

This is the MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="600" Width="1080" Foreground="White" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <materialDesign:ColorZone Mode="PrimaryMid" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <materialDesign:PopupBox PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:ColorZone>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="326*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="GhostWhite">
            <Image Source="Assets/logo.png"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Menu" Margin="10"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the MainWindow.xaml.vb file:

```
Imports MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf
Imports Project.ViewModel


Partial Public Class MainWindow
Inherits Window

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim menuRegister = New List(Of SubItem)()
    menuRegister.Add(New SubItem("Customer"))
    menuRegister.Add(New SubItem("Providers"))
    menuRegister.Add(New SubItem("Employees"))
    menuRegister.Add(New SubItem("Products"))
    Dim item6 = New ItemMenu("Register", menuRegister, PackIconKind.Register)
    Dim menuSchedule = New List(Of SubItem)()
    menuSchedule.Add(New SubItem("Services"))
    menuSchedule.Add(New SubItem("Meetings"))
    Dim item1 = New ItemMenu("Appointments", menuSchedule, PackIconKind.Schedule)
    Dim menuReports = New List(Of SubItem)()
    menuReports.Add(New SubItem("Customers"))
    menuReports.Add(New SubItem("Providers"))
    menuReports.Add(New SubItem("Products"))
    menuReports.Add(New SubItem("Stock"))
    menuReports.Add(New SubItem("Sales"))
    Dim item2 = New ItemMenu("Reports", menuReports, PackIconKind.FileReport)
    Dim menuExpenses = New List(Of SubItem)()
    menuExpenses.Add(New SubItem("Fixed"))
    menuExpenses.Add(New SubItem("Variable"))
    Dim item3 = New ItemMenu("Expenses", menuExpenses, PackIconKind.ShoppingBasket)
    Dim menuFinancial = New List(Of SubItem)()
    menuFinancial.Add(New SubItem("Cash flow"))
    Dim item4 = New ItemMenu("Financial", menuFinancial, PackIconKind.ScaleBalance)
    Dim item0 = New ItemMenu("Dashboard", New UserControl(), PackIconKind.ViewDashboard)
    Menu.Children.Add(New UserControlMenuItem(item0))
    Menu.Children.Add(New UserControlMenuItem(item6))
    Menu.Children.Add(New UserControlMenuItem(item1))
    Menu.Children.Add(New UserControlMenuItem(item2))
    Menu.Children.Add(New UserControlMenuItem(item3))
    Menu.Children.Add(New UserControlMenuItem(item4))
End Sub
End Class
```

This is the ItemMenu Class:

```
Imports MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf

Namespace ViewModel
Public Class ItemMenu
    Public Sub New(ByVal header As String, ByVal subItems As List(Of SubItem), ByVal icon As PackIconKind)
        header = header
        subItems = subItems
        icon = icon
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal header As String, ByVal screen As UserControl, ByVal icon As PackIconKind)
        header = header
        screen = screen
        icon = icon
    End Sub

    Public Property Header As String
    Public Property Icon As PackIconKind
    Public Property SubItems As List(Of SubItem)
    Public Property Screen As UserControl
End Class
End Namespace
```

This is the SubItem Class:

```
Namespace ViewModel
Public Class SubItem
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal Optional screen As UserControl = Nothing)
        name = name
        screen = screen
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Screen As UserControl
End Class
End Namespace
```

This is the UserControlMenuItem.xaml file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlMenuItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Grid>
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding Path=Icon}" Width="15" Height="15" Margin="10 16" Foreground="White"/>
    <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListViewItemMenu" Content="{Binding Path=Header}" Padding="37 14" FontSize="15" Foreground="White"/>
    <Expander x:Name="ExpanderMenu" Header="{Binding Path=Header}" IsExpanded="False" Width="210" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" Foreground="White" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="20 5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

This is the UserControlMenuItem.xaml.vb file:

```
Imports Project.ViewModel

Partial Public Class UserControlMenuItem
Inherits UserControl

Public Sub New(ByVal itemMenu As ItemMenu)
    InitializeComponent()
    ExpanderMenu.Visibility = If(itemMenu.SubItems Is Nothing, Visibility.Collapsed, Visibility.Visible)
    ListViewItemMenu.Visibility = If(itemMenu.SubItems Is Nothing, Visibility.Visible, Visibility.Collapsed)
    Me.DataContext = itemMenu
End Sub
```

End Class

This is the Window when the app is running:
[image]

What I'm missing here?

Design cloned from [DropDownMenu](https://github.com/Abel13/DropdownMenu)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It was a detail I didn't realise. These are the corrected Classes:

The `ItemMenu` Class:

```
Imports MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf

Namespace ViewModel
Public Class ItemMenu
    Public Sub New(ByVal header As String, ByVal subItems As List(Of SubItem), ByVal icon As PackIconKind)
        Me.Header = header
        Me.SubItems = subItems
        Me.Icon = icon
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal header As String, ByVal screen As UserControl, ByVal icon As PackIconKind)
        Me.Header = header 
        Me.Screen = screen 
        Me.Icon = icon 
    End Sub

    Public Property Header As String
    Public Property Icon As PackIconKind
    Public Property SubItems As List(Of SubItem)
    Public Property Screen As UserControl
End Class
End Namespace
```

The `SubItem` Class:

```
Namespace ViewModel
Public Class SubItem
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal Optional screen As UserControl = Nothing)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Screen = screen
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Screen As UserControl
End Class
End Namespace
```

Just remained make reference to the Class with "Me" (`self` in other languages like Python) and then assign a value to the property:

```
Me.Header = header 'Example in ItemMenu Class
Me.Name = name     'Example in SubItem Class
```